# Trying to pull stock quote info from TDAmeritrade with Google Script with API needing authentication

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, curl, google-apps-script

I'm using an API from TD Ameritrade to pull stock ticker information.  The script needs authentication to pull real time data.  The CURL command is as follows:

curl -X GET --header "Authorization: " --header "Authorization: Bearer " "https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/AAPL/quotes?apikey="

I'm using a Google Script to read the data from the API, do some calculations, and then write the data to a Google Sheet.  Below is the script to authenticate, and it doesn't work.  Note that my access token and APIkeys are not displayed here and the text is noted by  and .  The script does not give an error message, and pulls (delayed) data.  I can tell the authentication isn't working right, because the data is delayed.  Testing on the TD Ameritrade site with authentication returns real time data.  So does running the CURL in a DOS box on my PC.

```
var ticker = "AAPL"
var options = {
    "method" : "GET",
    "Authorization" : "Bearer <access token>"
     }
var calltoAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/"+ticker+"/quotes?apikey=<APIkey>",options);
```

I'm fairly new at this and would appreciate any help

UPDATE: HERE IS THE CODE THAT WORKS

```
    var ticker = "APPL"

    var headers = {"Authorization":" Bearer <access token>"}
    var options = {"headers":headers}

    var calltoAPI=urlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/"+ticker+"/quotes?apikey=<apikey>",options);
```

Comment: Consider  answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61314712/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to convert the following curl command to Google Apps Script.

  - `curl -X GET --header "Authorization: " --header "Authorization: Bearer " "https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/AAPL/quotes?apikey="`
  - You have already confirmed that this curl command works fine.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? When `--header "Authorization: Bearer "` is used for Google Apps Script, please put it to the header object. So please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var options = {
    "method" : "GET",
    "Authorization" : "Bearer <access token>"
     }
```

#### To:

```
var options = {
  "method" : "GET",
  "headers": {"Authorization" : "Bearer <access token>"}
};
```

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

The requests of both your curl command and the modified script are the same. But if this didn't work, please confirm the tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I put the code that actually works in the original post.

Comment: @RollsRoyse Thank you for replying. I couldn't understand about your replying. If my answer was not useful for your situation, please tell me. I have to apologize. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: Your suggestion was very helpful Tanaike.  I'm new here and don't know how to put code in a comment, so I updated the original post to include the working code.