# Loading stock quotes from TD Ameritrade developer app into Sheets with Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I'm trying to use an API from TD Ameritrade to load stock info into a Google Sheet.

I've tried the following code:

```js
var ticker = "APPL"

    var headers = {"Authorization":" Bearer <access token>"}
    var options = {"headers":headers}

    var calltoAPI=urlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/"+ticker+"/quotes?apikey=<myapikey>",options);
```

I get the error: ReferenceError: urlFetchApp is not defined (line 6, file "Code"). However, in my developer app, I do get a return on APPL. Worth mentioning I'm not sure what belongs as the authorization Bearer access token and if that is the problem or part of a problem. I really don't know what to do next. The code was copied from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58945513/trying-to-pull-stock-quote-info-from-tdameritrade-with-google-script-with-api-ne). I added my question there but it was deleted for not being helpful, so I'm asking you all instead.

Comment: JavaScript is Case sensitive(uppercase/lowercase matters!)

Comment: I updated the code to this: **bold** `var ticker = "TRNX"

    var headers = {"Authorization":" Bearer <>"}
    var options = {"headers":headers}

    var calltoAPI=UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/TRNX/quotes?apikey=MYAPIKEY",options);` and get the error: Exception: Request failed for https://api.tdameritrade.com returned code 401. Truncated server response

Comment: For a different error, it's better to ask a new question. Alternatively [edit] this question to show the latest code and show what research you've done on the error and authorization.